# What is the source of this sloka mentioning gravity?

Tags: identification-request, shloka, science

What is the source of this sloka which mentions gravity?

> aakrishta-shaktishcha mahi tvayaa yat
>   kha-stham guru svaabhimukam svashaktyaa/
>
> aakrishyate tat patatiti khe
>   same samantat kva patatviyam khe//

(Reference : Jnani-Guru, Paramahansa Nigamannanda Sarasvati, Sarasvata Math, page 7).

meaning: The earth has attraction-power and therefore it attracts heavy things from up above. So the things fall on the earth. Otherwise what falls what on void?

Comment: Ok so it is not Janani (mother) right? also can you add the translation too so that others will know that it is related to gravity?

Comment: This is only a partial and maybe incorrect translation. For example, the first line says: 'Mahi (Earth) obtained the attraction power from you'.

Comment: @user1952500 no. mahi is in samvodhana

Comment: I was referring to `tvaya yat` which means `from you`. Do you have a prose order for this?

Comment: @user1952500 'tvaya yat' can never mean 'from you'. Do u know sanskrit at all :)

Comment: Sorry it's rusty. It means 'by you', but in my local tongue 'by and from' are similar and I use them badly in English.

Comment: @user1952500 its okay

Comment: Ok, so it means 'Oh Earth, the attractive power comes by(from) you'. What is the 'patviyam' form? I know it's from the 'pat' dhaatu but haven't seen something like that. What lakaara / kaaraka is it?

Comment: @user1952500 i think its patatu plus iyam

Comment: That should be patatviyam right (yan sandhi)?

Comment: @user1952500 yes u r correct.thats a typo

Comment: @user1952500 i hv corrected the typo.thanks for this

Answer (score 7):

It's from [Goladhyaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siddh%C4%81nta_Shiromani#Ganitadhyaya_and_Goladhyaya) of [**Siddhanta Shiromani**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siddh%C4%81nta_Shiromani), a work of [Bhaskaracharya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bh%C4%81skara_II) (a great mathematician and astronomer lived in 12th century) on astronomy.

Siddhanta Shiromani has four parts on particular subject/area:

1. Leelavati - Arithmetic
2. Bijaganita - Algebra
3. GrahaganitAdhayaya - Astronomy
4. Goladhyaya - Astronomy

The verse quoted in question is from Goladhyaya.

You can read Goladhyaya in Sanskrit at [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/GoladhyayaIBhaskar/page/n37). Quoting page-30 from book for reference (Indicated the verse with box):

> [image]

Quoting the text from [Sanskrit Wikisource](https://sa.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%83%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A0%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8D%3A%E0%A4%97%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%B2%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%AF%E0%A4%83_(%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%A6%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A7%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%B6%E0%A4%BF%E0%A4%B0%E0%A5%8B%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A3%E0%A5%87%E0%A4%83_%E0%A4%AA%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%B0%E0%A4%A5%E0%A4%AE%E0%A5%8B_%E0%A4%AD%E0%A4%BE%E0%A4%97%E0%A4%83).pdf/%E0%A5%A9%E0%A5%AD):

> यथोष्णताफनलयोश्च शीतता विधौ ङतिः के कठिनवमश्मनि ।
>   मरुच्चलो भूरचला स्वभावतो यतो विचित्रा बत वस्तुशक्तयः। ५॥
>
> **आकृष्टिशक्तिश्च मही तया यरखस्थं गुरु स्वाभिमुखं स्वशक्या ।
>
>   आकृष्यते तपततीव भाति समे समन्तात् पतत्वियं खे ॥ ६ ॥**

IAST of the emphasized verse is:

ākṛṣṭiśaktiśca mahī tayā yarakhasthaṃ guru svābhimukhaṃ svaśakyā ।
ākṛṣyate tapatatīva bhāti same samantāt patatviyaṃ khe ॥ 6 ॥

Comment: Excellent work.